# Replace values ​within a column of a table using Table Name and Column name in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, datatable, inputbox

I have the next table

| header1 | header2 | header3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| v | x | v |
| x | v | x |
|  | x | x |
| v | v | v |
| x | v | x |

I want to replace "x" for another value for each column, for example "true" for 1st column, "false"  for 2nd column and "else" for 3rd column.
Finally, this would be the result:

| header1 | header2 | header3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| v | false | v |
| true | v | else |
|  | false | else |
| v | v | v |
| true | v | else |

But the case is that I have to specify the sheet name and the table name (all tables have the same column names). So I came up with something like this, but obviously the code is wrong

```
Sub Macro1()
'
'
' 

Dim sheet_name As String
Dim table_name As String

sheet_name = InputBox("Sheet Name?", "enter the data")
table_name = InputBox("Table Name?", "enter the data")

With Worksheet(sheet_name).ListObjects(table_name)

.Range("[header1]").Select
Selection.Replace What:="x", Replacement:="true", LookAt:=xlPart _
    , SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
    ReplaceFormat:=False, FormulaVersion:=xlReplaceFormula2

.Range("[header2]").Select
Selection.Replace What:="x", Replacement:="false", LookAt:=xlPart _
    , SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
    ReplaceFormat:=False, FormulaVersion:=xlReplaceFormula2

.Range("[header3]").Select
Selection.Replace What:="x", Replacement:="else", LookAt:=xlPart _
    , SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
    ReplaceFormat:=False, FormulaVersion:=xlReplaceFormula2
End With
End Sub
```

If anyone has any better ideas or ways to correct this code, it would be very helpful.

Comment: `.ListColumns("header1").DataBodyRange.Replace ...` to avoid the Select on only replace the values in the table body.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this code.

I like to have kind of configuration for such settings - it's much easier to make changes, e.g. if you want to change the replace-values.

regarding replacement for true/false: you need to put a ' in front of the value while replacing - otherwise Excel turns it into `TRUE` `FALSE` (a value, not a string)

```vb
Public Sub replaceXValues()
Dim sheet_name As String
Dim table_name As String

sheet_name = InputBox("Sheet Name?", "enter the data")
table_name = InputBox("Table Name?", "enter the data")

Dim lo As ListObject
Set lo = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(sheet_name).ListObjects(table_name)

Set lo = ActiveSheet.ListObjects(1)


Dim strFind As String
strFind = "x"

Dim arrReplace(1 To 3) As String
arrReplace(1) = "true"
arrReplace(2) = "false"
arrReplace(3) = "else"


Dim lc As ListColumn, i As Long
For i = 1 To UBound(arrReplace)
    Set lc = lo.ListColumns(i)
    lc.DataBodyRange.replace strFind, "'" & arrReplace(i), LookAt:=xlWhole
Next

End Sub
```

Obviously you would need an error handler in case sheet- or table-name do not exist.

Comment: THANKS!! I found the way to do it 
But now i have other issue, if the word to replace is "VERDADERO" (TRUE)  or "FALSO" (FALSE) the code doesn't make any change. I made another post about this type of error.

Error trying to replace the words "VERDADERO" or "FALSO" in vba

Comment: Check for an apostroph in front of "VERDADERO"